# Dynamically Passed index hints are failing in few scenarios in dbms_sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pass index hints dynamically to sql queries using dbms_sql.

```
    Select :hint emp_name from EMPLOYEE emp; -> is working fine
```

Below cases parsing is failing and getting errors.

ex:

```
    Select :hint count(1) from EMPLOYEE emp;
    Select :hint Distinct emp_name from EMPLOYEE emp;
    Select :hint emp.emp_name from EMPLOYEE emp;
```

Getting error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

How to handle index hints in the above failed cases?

Oracle version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

Here example hint:
l_sql_hint := /*+ full(emp) */

Code:

```
   /* First of all open a cursor. */
    curs_handle := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

    /* Now parse the query */
    dbms_sql.parse(curs_handle, l_sql, dbms_sql.native);

    IF l_sql_hint IS NOT NULL THEN
        dbms_sql.bind_variable(curs_handle, ':hint', l_sql_hint);
    END IF;

    no_of_rows_affected := dbms_sql.EXECUTE(curs_handle);
```

Comment: Don't use bind variables, but SQL Injection instead. This is one of the good uses of SQL Injection.

Comment: Bind variables are not text placeholders. Their content is evaluated after the parsing is done and the plan is already prepared. The only way is to use concatenation (or better to collect up-to-date statistics).

Comment: Did you check what your 'working example' is actually returning? It is very probably returning the text of the hint in the column emp_name, for the reason the previous comment explained: bind variable are used to pass/return values from sql, not to change the sql text, like you want.